# C zip library that can create password protected zip files on windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, windows-7, zip

Anyone know of a C library that can create password protected zip files on windows? It appears that the option to password protect zip files with the built-in zip utility has been removed from windows 7, but I don't think this is an issue.

Can either zziplib or the 7-Zip SDK do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

7-Zip SDK (LZMA SDK) supports password protected archive.

<strike>Related SO post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221049/how-secure-is-7-zip</strike>

LZMA SDK:
http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Comment: LZMA SDK looks like it will work...its a shame there are no binary distributions though.

Comment: The LZMA SDK ended up being a pain to use, and I couldn't find a function for password-protecting archives. This little lib however, was a piece of cake to use! http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/zip_utils.aspx

Comment: However the password protected zip files it creates don't work on windows 7...windows 7 claims they are invalid when you try to open them.

Comment: @freedrull well.. I've planned to try this stuff my self but I didn't knew that windows support password protected zip files. Hm.. I tested right now. When I open and decompress a password protected zip file made by 7Zip, windows explorer reports error 0x80004005 (Win7). I think we should use 7Zip to decompress password protected zip files.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use .NET, check out DotNetZip: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

C++ .NET example to create password-protected ZIP:
http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DotNetZipHelp/Code%20Examples/Cpp.htm

Answer (score 0):

MINIZIP + zlib supports AES 256 encryption, and is very easy to use!

Code based on minizip unzip.c.
include stdio.h zip.h unzip.h

First, create a zip with a file inside with a password. 
The zip file must be in the same directory as the executable. 
Run the program from a prompt in the directory of the generated program. This example only extracts the first file!

```cpp
/*-----------start-------------- */
/*Tries to open the zip in the current directory.*/
unzFile zfile =  unzOpen("teste.zip");
if(zfile==NULL) 
{
    printf("Error!");
    return;
}

printf("OK Zip teste.zip opened...\n");


int err = unzGoToFirstFile(zfile);/*go to first file in zip*/
if (err != UNZ_OK)
{
    printf("error %d with zipfile in unzGoToFirstFile\n", err); 
    unzClose(zfile);/*close zip*/
}

/*At this point zfile points to the first file contained in the zip*/

char filename_inzip[256] = {0};/* The file name will be returned here */
unz_file_info file_info = {0};/*strcuture with info of the first file*/

err = unzGetCurrentFileInfo(zfile, &file_info, filename_inzip, sizeof(filename_inzip), NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
if (err != UNZ_OK)
{
    printf("error %d with zipfile in unzGetCurrentFileInfo\n",err);
}
else
{
    int len = 8192;/*size of chunk*/
    char buffer[8192]={0};/*buffer used to save uncompressed data*/
    printf("name of first file is :%s\n",filename_inzip);
    printf("uncompressed_size = %d\n",file_info.uncompressed_size);

    /*Use your password here, the same one used to create your zip */
    err = unzOpenCurrentFilePassword(zfile, "yourpassword");
    if (err != UNZ_OK)
        printf("error %d with zipfile in unzOpenCurrentFilePassword\n", err);
    else
        printf("password ok\n");

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename_inzip, "wb");/*file for data binary type*/
    if (fp != NULL) 
    {
        do
        {/*read the current file returned by unzGoToFirstFile to buffer in chunks of the 8192*/
            err = unzReadCurrentFile(zfile, &buffer, len );
            if (err < 0)
            {
                printf("error %d with zipfile in unzReadCurrentFile\n", err);
                break;
            }
            if (err == 0)
                break;
            /*Save the chunk read to the file*/
            if (fwrite(&buffer, err, 1, fp) != 1)/*if error break*/
            {
                printf("error %d in writing extracted file\n", errno);
                err = UNZ_ERRNO;
                break;
            }/*else continue*/
        }
        while (err > 0);
        /*close file*/
        fclose(fp);
    }
}

unzClose(zfile);
```